# Vue.js application not working on Android

Tags: android, vue.js

All works fine in newer Chrome, Firefox and Safari, just not on Android, possibly some older devices or browsers, I don't know the versions because the people trying to use it are on a different continent and brain dead and can't figure out their software version. Took me two hours over the phone to get a screenshot, looks like this:

[image: screenshot from Android device]

I have already switched from `<template>` to `<script type="x/template">`

Anyone else ran into this issue?

Later edit: I just had this happening on iPhone 6 too for some users.

Later edit 2: This is also happening on Safari on mac on occasion. Can't figure out a pattern.

PS for them professional deletionists: hope this isn't "off-topic" in some mysterious way? If it is, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Hehe - "professional deletionists" - I hope they do not delete it ;-). I upvoted your question. Is vue.js working well for you?

Comment: Thanks! Generally it is, we've been able to do great things much faster than with angular, react or ember, it's just those little details that are still a pain to work out, but hopefully we'll figure everything out

Comment: I'm having a similar issue unfortunately ... on my desktop everything works as expected, but on my Samsung ... not so well ... still researching this issue ...

Comment: Still happening here as well Cristi, for now I added some code that checks whether the Vue app has booted properly (by checking a computed property inside a try/catch), otherwise displays a dialog pitching a browser/OS update.

Comment: Did you solve this, I have this problem on Android 8.1 in Chrome. Nothing is shown in chrome and there is no developers console.

Comment: Negative. This issue keeps popping up from time to time. At this point we're just telling them to get rid of the archaic devices or if their accounts are large enough we're sending them new phones on the house.